# GPS coordinates conversion

Tags: coordinates, gps

How to transfer these  GPS coordinates into conventional coordinates of long and lat? (the first column is East and the second column is North)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShuoH.jpg

Comment: It would help to know an EPSG code for those coordinates.

Comment: Coordinates look like UTM84-40N, EPSG:32640. What software do you have? What have you tried?

Comment: I use Google Earth and ArcMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input is UTM Zone 40N, and you want WGS-84 lat/long, you can use
`cs2cs` from proj.

Here is a simple example, for the Yas Island case:

```
bradh@audax:~$ cs2cs +proj=utm +zone=40 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  +to +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs << EOF
255393.4 2711670.81
EOF
54d35'10.122"E  24d29'58.307"N 0.000
```

You can do multiple lines, but since you've only provided an image, I just typed out one.

Answer (score 2):

Go to projfinder.com, zoom in on Yas Island and put the coordinates of Yas Island from the spreadsheet image into the boxes at the top, and hit "Find My Projection". It will then list some possible projections of those coordinates that are near the centre of the zoomed map (where the target marker is).

[image]

If you know *precisely* to the metre where your spreadsheet coordinate is meant to be, then you can probably figure out which of those UTM Zone 40N possibles this could be, otherwise go for the latest WGS84 projection system (EPSG:32640 Name:WGS 84 / UTM zone 40N) and convert to lat-long using whatever software you have to hand and you may have to live with a few metres or a hundred metres of uncertainty/error.